# How to add multiple plot figures in one window with python?

Tags: python, csv, visualization

Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I have a code that reads  from csv file and plots data of different types and I need that plots to be in one window. How can I achieve this? This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as ppl

def point_plot(num, x, y, type, title, color, save):

    ppl.figure(num)
    ppl.plot(x, y, type, color=color)
    ppl.title(title)
    ppl.grid()
    ppl.savefig(save)

def linear_plot(data_, title, save):
    
    data_.plot()
    ppl.title(title)
    ppl.grid()
    ppl.savefig(save)

f = open("sensor_data17.csv", encoding="utf-8")
csv_read = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")

header = next(csv_read)

f.close()

data_csv = pd.read_csv("sensor_data17.csv", header=None, names=header, skiprows=1, delimiter=";")

point_plot(1, data_csv["Pose X"], data_csv["Pose Y"], "o", "Pose", "black", "A_Pose.png")
point_plot(2, list(range(1, 243)), data_csv["Dust PPM"], "o", "Dust PPM", "green", "A_Dust.png")
linear_plot(data_csv[["Pressure Pa"]], "Pressure Pa", "A_Pressure.png")
linear_plot(data_csv[["Lightning Lx", "Air quality PPM", "Temperature C","Humidity %","Altitude m","Loudness"]], "CSV Data", "A_Data.png")

ppl.show()
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To fit NxM plots in one window you can use either

1. [`subplots(N,M)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) or
2. [`GridSpec(N,M)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html)

Among the two, `subplots` is easier to use and gives an evenly divided plot space. However, if you desire to divide the plotting space in a non-even way (such as in shown image) use can use `GridSpec`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the exact case with 2 figures, try ading

```
def point_plot(num, SUBPLOT, x, y, type, title, color, save)  # SUBPLOT

ppl.figure(num)
plt.subplot(SUBPLOT) #<--------- this whole line
ppl.plot(x, y, type, color=color)
```

and when calling

```
point_plot(1, 211, data_csv["Pose X"], data_csv["Pose Y"], "o", "Pose", "black", "A_Pose.png") # number 211
```

you can refer to [matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/multiple_figs_demo.html)